# Provide System.Web.HttpRequest as a parameter to an ActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem because on my Controller I have a method, which one, needs a parameter and that parameter is a System.Web.HttpRequest type. But i don't have any idea of how to pass it to my controller and how to use it... I've tried with an Ajax function. Does someone has an idea?

Comment: If you have a controller action that returns an ActionResult, you typically wouldn't call that via AJAX. You would typically do a Post or a Get to the controller action and it would return some ActionResult. If you are looking to get something off of the HttpRequest, you should be able to access the entire request using the Request property of the controller. Not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: HttpRequest can not be passed via Ajax to an Action method since Request object is part of any controller that have ActionResult methods, so you can access Request object into an Action method as indicated by randyh22. What do specifically you need to do?

Comment: Like you said, an Ajax Request can not make it; i am trying to make an error controller which gives you back an error display but directly using a System.Web.HttpRequest Object.

Comment: My solution was in the backend use the next code:  `HttpContext.Current` and gives back the complete object ready to manage the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the next code: `HttpContext.Current` and gives back the complete object ready to manage the error.